# How to apply different width stored in PHP to 3 identical DIVs (using same CSS)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, variables

I have a graph which has some CSS styling. It's width is set in WordPress, so I need to use php to apply it.

At first I have applied the width by adding some inline CSS in HTML. This worked well even for for few graphs on one page. But when I wanted to add responsiveness it occurred inline CSS is overwriting media queries and breaking responsiveness. So I decided I will do it by applying PHP variables directly to CSS in the way it is described here:

http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/

The problem is when the following situation happens:

I have the rule:

```
.graph {
    width: <?php echo $graph-width; ?>;
       }
```

I have 3 graphs on one page using this class. Each graph has different width specified in WordPress Admin Panel.

How to apply those different widths stored in PHP to all 3 graphs on the page.

Please note I never know how many graphs will be on one page.

Comment: Have the div's class or id got any form originality to identify them from each other? Has the content got any form of identification?

Comment: You could embed styles in the html tag itself. Eg. <div style="width:<?php echo $graph-width; ?>">....</div>

Comment: @Vector The DIVs are identical without any ID. I could think of adding ID but how would it help?

Comment: @bumperbox - This is what I did and it worked. But as I wrote it was also overwriting mediaqueries and breaking responsivness.

Comment: @HoGo sorry i missed that bit, must have been reading too fast

Comment: You could overwrite inline styles with the use of `!important` with your media queries, but That's the lazy option and not recommended.

Comment: @Vector - I know, but I do not like such approach.

Comment: are you open to use jQuery?

Comment: @BojanaŠekeljić - if there is no other way I could use JavaScript or jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the time to test this now but here's approach that might work. Have your divs created with another class that contains incrementing numbers, ie. container-1, container-2, container-n.

Then with jQuery you could do something like this:

```
var i = 1;
function widthAdder() {
    if(i % 2 === 0) { //this is every second element
         $('.container-' + i).css(width: "100px"); //here you set the width
         i++;
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) { // this is every third
         $('.container-' + i).css(width: "150px"); //here you set the width
         i++;
    } else { //this is every first
         $('.container-' + i).css(width: "200px"); //here you set the width
         i++;
    }
}

widthAdder();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I did it in similar way with JS. I think there is no other way.